# SQL Server 2016 Express Edition installation fails in Windows 10 Pro (x64)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying desperately to install SQL Server 2016 Express in my Windows 10 Pro (x64), but it fails every time at 94%, saying:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbAZr.png]

The full summary and error log:

http://pastebin.com/eVPGBiTK

Answer (score 0):

The error is:
"Service Master Key could not be decrypted using one of its encryptions. See sys.key_encryptions for details"

This following link sounds like the issue, although it is for SQL Server 2014, it may be worth a try. See the section on what to do if it happens during install.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3091643

Another suggestion is to try setting the SQL Service to use the System account or another one you created with full rights.

Alternatively, start the SQL Service up in single user mode if it will start and check that table. But that's a bit advanced if you're not used to SQL Server.